# Can I create an instance of a service with Hilt in Android?

Tags: android, dagger-hilt

Normally, I can use Code B  to create instance automatically by Hilt.

There is  a Service class of Android Studio in Code A, can I use  Hilt to create an instance of Service ?

**Code A**

```
   class RecordService : Service() {
        private val CHANNEL_ID ="channel__voice_record"

        private var mRecorder: MediaRecorder? = null

        override fun onBind(intent: Intent): IBinder {
            return MyBinder()
        }

        inner class MyBinder : Binder() {
            val service: RecordService
            get() = this@RecordService
       }
        ...
   }  

  fun bindService() {
        Intent(mApplication , RecordService::class.java).also { intent ->
            mApplication.bindService(intent, serviceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE)
        }
    }

    fun unbindService() {
        Intent(mApplication, RecordService::class.java).also { intent ->
            mApplication.unbindService(serviceConnection)
            mService?.stopForeground(true)
            mService?.stopSelf()
        }
    }
```

**Code B**

```
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
@Module
abstract class SoundModule {
    @Binds
    abstract fun bindIHandleMeter(impl: HandleMeter): IHandleMeter
}


@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
@Module
object ObjectModule {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideMediaPlayer(): MediaPlayer {
        return MediaPlayer()
    }
}
```

**Added Content**

To Mikhail Guliaev: Thanks!

But from the [article](https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-android), it seems that the `Service` class  can be instanced automaticaly by Hilt, you can see Image.

**Image**

[image]

**Newly Added Content**

To Mikhail Guliaev: Thanks again!

Can  I use Code C without adding he code `@AndroidEntryPoint` ?

**Code C**

```
class RecordService @Inject constructor(
   private val translateService: ITranslateService
): Service() {
    ...
}
```

And more,  can Hilt create the instance of RecordService  in Code C automatically ? and  can I use an instance created by Hilt just like Code D?

**Code D**

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class ActivityMain : ComponentActivity() {
       @Inject lateinit var recordService RecordService
         ...
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't create instances of Activity components by yourself (it doesn't matter, it will be created by you in code or provided from a Hilt module). To be precise, you will be able to create instances of a `Service` class, but you will not be able to use it properly.

`Activity` and `Service` instances are being created by the Android system, when you call `Context.startActivity(intent: Intent)` or `Context.startService(intent: Intent)` methods. This is the only right way to start these Android components.

**Update**

The update about your screenshot. Supporting of `Service` means that you can mark your `Service` class with `@AndroidEntryPoint` annotation to tell hilt to inject dependencies into your `Service` class. Check out this snippet below. Here by marking your service with `@AndroidEntryPoint` annotation you tell Hilt to inject properties to this class, and therefore the `someRecorder` variable will be injected to your `RecordService` by Hilt.

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class RecordService : Service() {

    @Inject
    lateinit var someRecorder: Recorder

    ...

}
```

**Update №2**
No, you can't use the code from snippet C. Because as I described above, Android system creates `Service` class automatically under the hood. The correct injection of parameters to `Service` you can see in my code above.

But you can use the code from `Snippet D`. Because the Activty will be created by Android, and then `@AndroidEntryPoint` annotation tells `Hilt` to inject parameters which are marked with `@Inject` annotation

Comment: Tried to explain in more details - please check out my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks! Would you please to see my newly added content  in the question?

Comment: You're welcome. I answered to it too. If anything became clear, would you mark the answer as approved please?

Answer (score 1):

An `@AndroidEntryPoint` does not create generate Android components in the dependency tree. It's just telling hilt to perform dependency injections automatically.

If you would be on Dagger 2 without Hilt, your entry points would have some `DaggerComponent.build(whatever()).inject(this)` somewhere in `onCreate()` so that you can easily use field injections via `@Inject`.

Thus `@AndroidEntryPoint` is not creating instances of your service, but rather it is telling Hilt/Dagger that you can perform dependency injection on these classes as they are Android Components. That's what the docs are mentioning too, not the other way around.

DI or no DI, Hilt or whatever, you do not create an instance of the service, but rather you bind/unbind to it (or start or stop it). It's the responsibility of the system to give it to you without a crash if you have set it up correctly. You can actually create a wrapper class that provides this service after binding to it is successful and then inject that one, but that's probably not needed for your case.

Therefore, just use the servie as we classically use it:

```
private val serviceConnection = object: ServiceConnection {
   override fun onServiceConnected() = ...
   override fun onServiceDisconnected() = ...
}
```

Then get the service instance that you need.

Or, go for a `WorkManager` if a `Service` is too much. But there it's the same logic too.

To answer your last question, code C won't work. These are entry points that technically should not be in the dependency tree at all because the system is responsible for creating them. (you have to include them in the manifest too). Actually did you try code C? I predict Hilt should give you an error already.

Edit: Ok I tried the code C myself, it appears Hilt does not care and provides this instance, but this does not mean that you should go this way because you will never be able to use it as a `Service` but just as a normal instance, this means you cannot get the callbacks that come from the system (`onBind`, `onCreate` etc).